# Negative-norm States and Unitary Representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This is a question coming from my physics learning. When reading the book *Conformal Field Theory* by Di Francesco et al, in Section 7.1.1 discussing the $su(2)$ algebra of angular momentum, the author says below eq. (7.3)

> states of negative norm generically appear when $m$ decreases below $-j$ ; the representation is then non-unitary.

This seems to be following from the authors' unusual definition of **unitary representations**: in section 7.2.1, the authors states that

> A representation of the Virasoro algebra is said to be unitary if it contains no negative-norm states.

From my knowledge, the traditional definition of a unitary representation should be that each element in the group is represented as a unitary operator/matrix. So my questions are

- What is the relation between negative norm of basis states and unitarity of a representation?
- Or is there some difference between unitary representation of a *group* and that of a *Lie algebra*?

Comment: Extra details surrounding the computations that lead to the discussion in the beginning of your post would help a lot I think.

Comment: I find the same question already asked in the [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317028/222821). It seems that there is no relation between unitarity and negative norm states.